# Error in "make" command while installing ruby1.9.3 in Kali

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am running Kali,
Trying to install ruby1.9.3 after having successfully installed SNORT, PULLEDPORK an BARNYARD2

```
%%%%%% EXECUTING THESE COMMANDS
1) %%% wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tar.gz
2) %%% tar -xvzf ruby-1.9.3-p551.tar.gz
3) %%% cd ruby-1.9.3-p551
4) %%% ./configure
5) %%% make
6) %%% make install
```

1st 3 commands run OK,
getting ERRORS n Warnings on (5) make command.

Output like this:-

```
    root@kali:~/snort_src/ruby-1.9.3-p551# make
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -shared
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration 
        XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
        CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I.
        DLDFLAGS =  
        SOLIBS = 
    linking miniruby
    rbconfig.rb unchanged
    generating enc.mk
    generating prelude.c
    compiling prelude.c
    linking static-library libruby-static.a
    ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
    generating encdb.h
    encdb.h unchanged
    making enc
    make[1]: Entering directory '/root/snort_src/ruby-1.9.3-p551'
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'enc'.
    .
    .        
    .
    compiling ossl_ssl.c
    ossl_ssl.c:116:27: error: ‘SSLv3_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
    OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3),
                       ^
    ossl_ssl.c:106:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
    #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                 ^
    ossl_ssl.c:117:27: error: ‘SSLv3_server_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
         OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3_server),
                       ^
    ossl_ssl.c:106:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
     #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                 ^
    ossl_ssl.c:118:27: error: ‘SSLv3_client_method’ undeclared here (not in a function)
         OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(SSLv3_client),
                       ^
    ossl_ssl.c:106:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
     #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                 ^
    ossl_ssl.c: In function ‘ossl_sslctx_session_new_cb’:
    ossl_ssl.c:382:35: warning: variable ‘ret_obj’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         VALUE ary, ssl_obj, sess_obj, ret_obj;
                                       ^
    ossl_ssl.c: In function ‘ossl_sslctx_session_remove_cb’:
    ossl_ssl.c:431:38: warning: variable ‘ret_obj’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         VALUE ary, sslctx_obj, sess_obj, ret_obj;
                                  ^
    ossl_ssl.c: In function ‘ssl_servername_cb’:
    ossl_ssl.c:508:25: warning: variable ‘ret_obj’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
                 VALUE ary, ssl_obj, ret_obj;
                     ^
    Makefile:269: recipe for target 'ossl_ssl.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/snort_src/ruby-1.9.3-p551/ext/openssl'
    exts.mk:126: recipe for target 'ext/openssl/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/snort_src/ruby-1.9.3-p551'
    uncommon.mk:178: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
    make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Kindly suggest a way out.

Comment: Support for Ruby 1.9.3 has ended more than [a year ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/02/23/support-for-ruby-1-9-3-has-ended/). Why do you want to use such an old version?

Comment: I m trying to install SNORBY and it only accepts Ruby1.9.3